# Is it possible to put tags on 'waf-regional' web-acls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

When trying to list tags for waf-regional:

```
aws waf-regional list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn <web-acl-arn-here>
```

I get the following response

```
An error occurred (WAFInvalidParameterException) when calling the ListTagsForResource operation:
```

According to the documentation this seems to be correct.

The same call to normal waf works:

```
aws waf list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn <web-acl-arn-here>
{
    "NextMarker": "",
    "TagInfoForResource": {
        "ResourceARN": "<web-acl-arn-here>",
        "TagList": []
    }
}
```

Attempting to add tags to a waf-regional web-acl has the same result:

```
aws waf-regional tag-resource --resource-arn <web-acl-arn-here> --tags Key=Name,Value=TestRegionalv1

An error occurred (WAFInvalidParameterException) when calling the TagResource operation:
```

It seems to me that waf-regional just doesn't support tags at all - but documentation seems to point to it being supported. Does anyone have an idea what is the case here?

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/waf-regional/tag-resource.html
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/waf-regional/list-tags-for-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug, I would cut a ticket to AWS support to dig in deeper. Note that there's new WAF (called wafv2) that service team recommend to use.

Comment: Yep OK I figured - I'll create a report on github to address it (I found a few other issues to do with WAF as I was building some stuff and did the same there).

Yeah I need to support was, waf-regional and wafv2 unfortunately - wafv2 has a lot less issues on this kind of stuff!